# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Poker Stack Exchange](http://poker.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://poker.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 6 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [The more advice I read - the worse I play. What am I doing wrong?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/the-more-advice-i-read-the-worse-i-play-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Can I move HUD info on PokerTracker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/can-i-move-hud-info-on-pokertracker)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What I did was right?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/what-i-did-was-right)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Pocket Aces in 9-handed](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/pocket-aces-in-9-handed)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [AKo all in v 57o?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/ako-all-in-v-57o)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [In live play, why do poker players wait their turn before looking at their cards?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/in-live-play-why-do-poker-players-wait-their-turn-before-looking-at-their-cards)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)